# multiple kernel calls in for loop

Tags: ios, macos, metal

I want to carry multiple kernel calls in for a loop. The codes I tried is listed as follow:

```
   id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
   NSLog(@"Device: %@", [device name]);

   id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];

   NSError * ns_error = nil;
   //id<MTLLibrary> defaultLibrary = [device newDefaultLibrary];
   id<MTLLibrary>defaultLibrary = [device    newLibraryWithFile:@"/Users/i/tmp/tmp6/s.metallib" error:&ns_error];
   //get fuction
   id<MTLFunction> newfunc = [ defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"sigmoid" ];

   // Buffer for storing encoded commands that are sent to GPU
   id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];

   //set input and output data
   float tmpbuf[2][1000];
   float outbuf[2][1000];
   float final_out[2][1000];
   for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
   {
      tmpbuf[0][i] = i;
      outbuf[0][i] = 0;
      tmpbuf[1][i] = 10*i;
      outbuf[1][i] = 0;
    }

    int tmp_length = 1000*sizeof(float);
    //get pipelinestat
    id<MTLComputePipelineState> cpipeline[2];
    cpipeline[0]    = [device newComputePipelineStateWithFunction: newfunc error:&ns_error ];
    cpipeline[1]    = [device newComputePipelineStateWithFunction: newfunc error:&ns_error ];
    id<MTLBuffer> inVectorBuffer[2];
    id<MTLBuffer> outVectorBuffer[2];
    id <MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeCommandEncoder[2];
    computeCommandEncoder[0] = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
    computeCommandEncoder[1] = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];

    MTLSize ts= {10, 1, 1}; 
    MTLSize numThreadgroups = {100, 1, 1};

    for( int k = 0; k < 2; k++ )
    {
         inVectorBuffer[k]  = [device newBufferWithBytes: tmpbuf[k] length: tmp_length options: MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault ];
         [computeCommandEncoder[k] setBuffer: inVectorBuffer[k] offset: 0 atIndex: 0 ];
         outVectorBuffer[k] = [device newBufferWithBytes: outbuf[k] length: tmp_length options: MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault ];
         [computeCommandEncoder[k] setBuffer: outVectorBuffer[k] offset: 0 atIndex: 1 ];


         [computeCommandEncoder[k] setComputePipelineState:cpipeline[k] ];
         [computeCommandEncoder[k] dispatchThreadgroups:numThreadgroups threadsPerThreadgroup:ts];
         [computeCommandEncoder[k] endEncoding ];

    }

    [ commandBuffer commit];
    [ commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];enter code here
```

It couldnot work properly. when it was run, the following information was reproted

```
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/GPUDriversIntel/GPUDriversIntel-10.14.58/Common/MTLRenderer/Intel/ivb/MTLIGAccelCommandBuffer.m:240: failed assertion `Already have uncommitted encoder'
 Abort trap: 6
```

Could anyone point out the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: inside the loop you are ending the encoding at each iteration but you never commit, only once, outside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one compute command encoder (per command buffer) active at a time. Instead of creating multiple encoders outside your loop, consider creating the command encoder *inside* the loop and ending encoding on it before the next loop iteration.

Comment: Warrenm was right. One computeCommandEncoder corresponds to one task, and should be created inside the loop.

Comment: You can also reuse the same compute command encoder over and over. There is no reason to call endEncoding in the loop here. That would allow you to make the command encoder outside the loop.